# Rotate array left or right by a set number of positions in o(n) complexity

Tags: c, rotation, shift

I want to write a program that shifts an array by a set number of positions right or left based on the user's input (positive ->, negative <-). The program has to have O(n) complexity. I've written it this way but it doesn't work as it should. In the example the output should be "2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1" but in my version is "6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void rotate(int *array, int N, int D);

int main(){
    int i;
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    rotate(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int), 5);

    for(i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++)
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);

    return 0;
}

void rotate(int *array, int N, int D){
    int i, j, *tmp, d;

    tmp = malloc(abs(D) * sizeof(int));

    if(D<0){
        d = abs(D);
        for(i=d; i<N; i++){
            tmp[i%d] = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i-d];
            array[i-d] = tmp[i%d];
        }
    }
    if(D>0){
        for(i=(N-D-1); i>=0; i--){
            tmp[i%D] = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+D];
            array[i+D] = tmp[i%D];
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Small correction: the title should say "Rotate" rather than "shift" - they are different concepts.

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of user input? I assume it's that `D` you have in `rotate()`?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, exactly, it is D, when i test the function, I pass it manually. When it will be working, it will be scanf... It doesn't really matter atm how I pass that number, it's just the number of postions to rotate the array.

Comment: So far you've told a story: you want to write a program, it needs to have a certain behaviour and performance characteristics, and it doesn't work. There's no question in there. That's just a list of facts. What is your question? Remember, **StackOverflow is not a service for debugging your buggy code**.  It's for *specific technical questions*.

Comment: The way to debug your code is: find a case that doesn't work. Write down **on paper** a list of *everything* -- EVERYTHING -- your program should do with that case. Now step through your code in the debugger. The moment something happens that you didn't write down, that's the bug.

Comment: @EricLippert, excuse me, I thought I could ask if someone could tell me what's wrong with my code. My question is how to make a program that rotates an array given the conditions I've written. I posted my buggy code just because it seemed to me more respectful towards people answering to see that I've at least tried writing it before asking online and taking time from them to read it.

Comment: @user3338768: You have demonstrated that you can write buggy code; **you have not demonstrated that you've attempted to debug it**, and that is (apparently) what you are asking people to do for you! Show some effort here. Your code doesn't work, ok, fine. What have you tried to do to find the bug? Where did you get stuck? Come up with a **specific question where the answer will get you unstuck**. "Where is my bug?" is not a specific question.

Comment: @EricLippert you're right, I didn't realize it in the first place, not used to asking coding questions online. I'll try to debug the code with the debugger. Sorry for the incovenience/rudeness.

Comment: Do you really need to rotate the array?   If you can just adjust the index you can get the effect of the rotation without the cost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jon Bentley in Programming Pearls Column 2 describes what has came to be known as the most elegant, efficient solution.

> The rotation algorithm uses a function `reverse()` that reverses
>   subsequences of the array. Quoting from the column:
>
> Let's view the problem as transforming the array `ab` into the array
>   `ba`, but let's also assume that we have a function that reverses the
>   elements in a specified portion of the array. Starting with ab, we
>   reverse a to get a_r b, reverse b to get a_r b_r, and then reverse the
>   whole thing to get (a_r b_r)_r, which is exactly ba.

This is what you need. The input from the user defines the place where you will partition the array into two blocks A and B. Here's my implementation:

```
void reverse(int a[], int sz) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = sz; i < j; i++, j--) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
  }
}

void rotate(int array[], int size, int amt) {
  if (amt < 0)
    amt = size + amt;
  reverse(array, size-amt-1);
  reverse(array+size-amt, amt-1);
  reverse(array, size-1);
}
```

I tested it and it's working. Also, note how negative rotations are handled: rotating an array of `size` elements `amt` to the left (i.e. with negative values) is the same as rotating it `size+amt` to the right.

Enjoy the elegant code, and don't forget to include credits in a comment (to Jon Bentley, of course).

Comment: Thank you, it is interesting indeed, it probably wouldn't have crossed my mind.

Answer (score 2):

For right rotate use:

```
temp[0]=a[0];
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    temp[i%2]=a[(i*d)%n];
    a[(i*d)%n]=temp[(i+1)%2];
}
```

For left rotate use:

```
temp[0]=a[0];
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    temp[i%2]=a[(i*(n-d))%n];
    a[(i*(n-d))%n]=temp[(i+1)%2];
}
```

where a[n] is the array and d is the number of positions you want to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

you are just swapping elements positions: element at position 1 is put at position 6 and vice versa... You should rewrite the last part. There are two ways to go:

- allocate a new array and copy your values one by one
- just save one value in tmp, and shift the others

Comment: This is a known problem. See my answer, there's an elegant solution.

Comment: This takes `O(n)`of time which is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial approach would be to rotate, but looking beyond that, why not try just repositioning the elements of the array/list.

```
def circularArrayRotation(a, k):
    k=k%len(a)
    b=a[len(a)-k:len(a)]
    #print(b)
    a=b+a[0:len(a)-k]
    print(a)
```

Thats right rotation, for left rotation just flip

`b=a[k:len(a)] and a=b+a[0:k]`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Please be little more cautious when posting an answer. I see some code that was not parsed as such because you did not indent it correctly. Moreover in the code you provide I do not see what the parameter `queries` is for and I do not see `len-k-1` anywhere nor `a=0`. Please edit to improve.

Comment: You have my apologies @GabrielDevillers. I shall edit my asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the *Reversal Algorithm* described in the accepted answer, another well-known algorithm is *Dolphin Algorithm* (commonly referred as *Juggling Algorithm*).

It does not need any temporary buffer, and "rotates" specific subsets of the array; there are total of `gcd(N,D)` such subsets.
Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321216/rotating-an-array-using-juggling-algorithm) for the source code, which also discusses the algorithm's underlying mathematics.

[This](https://hdl.handle.net/1813/6292) article describes the algorithm in detail (and why it is named after dolphins).

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, i have now specified my association to the linked article.